# Have a project half don in mvvp by using Web Client Software Factory 2010 can we continue the rest in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a big web application developed in mvvp using Web Client Software Factory 2010 the project was started 4-5 years ago and was not completed due to some reasons .

Now, we are trying to complete the rest of the project in mvc razor .

can anyone tell me is this possible ?

technically what i want to do is to have both mvvp and mvc used to develop one web application, that is half in mvvp and the rest in mvc . now there might be a question "why not do the web app completely in mvc instead of using mvvp and mvc "  the answer for the would be that half of is it already don in mvvp .

Comment: Hi @rajdarshan - I'm not really sure what you're asking here. The question  seems very general. you'll generally get a better response (and more help) if you ask *specific* technical questions. Perhaps think a bit about exactly what you need, and update your question reflect this.